# Samsung GSII-GTi9100 with CM12 - no USB connection

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, usb, samsung-galaxy-s-2, linux

I have installed CM12 from SDCard.

Device is running fine. It charges normaly from usb socket. But I need to access developer options and run code through ADB.

I have ADB set up on my ubuntu16.04 machine and have tried every option to enable USB debugging. I have added the OEM code to the adb_usb.ini file and have created the 51-android.rules file at the sugested places. However, my phone refuses to make the USB connection to the computer. I enable developers options and usb debugging. Connect usb cable to device and computer. I go to Settings>Storage>Overflow(...)>USB connections and phone responds with a single "USB not connected" message.

LinuxPC-side:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I think my phone is the culprit because other devices connect fine, so I know its not my cable or my computer. Maybe I missed a step on the configuration for ADB? Can someone lend me a hand?